# How to pass constraint values for annotaions dynamically through expression languange. Eg: @Size("${app.name.maxSize}")

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, jakarta-validation

Is it possible for the arguments passed to the constraint annotations to be passed dynamically using expression language. Its a generic requirement that could apply to any annotation, in example given in title its a @Size annotation but it can be any other annotation like @Pattern or a custom constraint.

Project i am working on is a spring boot project. with hibernate validator.
I understand that the annotations are applied on classes are simple pojos and are not spring beans thus spring will not process them for spel.

I do not expect these values to change at runtime but looking for a way to provide them via external configuration.

validators do support expression language for messages but not for constraint attributes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.